# How to use replaceAll when input contains spaces

Tags: java, replace

I have a newbie question about `replaceAll` method on String. It works fine as long as the input does not contain any type of space (breaking/non-breaking etc).

How to sanitize the input so it covers all cases for special space characters and I can use something like this:

```
String replaced = replaced.replaceAll("my-test (2)", "test"); // not working
```

I tried various types of regex with `\\s`, `\u00A0` etc.

EDIT: I noticed that the braces are also causing some problems with replaceAll.

This is my case:

```
"my-value (2)".replaceAll("my-value (2)", "test);
```

Comment: What is the expected output given the input `my-test (2)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use here:

```
String input = "my-value (2)";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\bmy-value\\s*\\(2\\)(?!\\S)", "test");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints: `test`

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
\b        word boundary
my-value  match "my-value"
\s*       zero or more whitespace characters
\(2\)     match "(2)"
(?!\S)    assert that what follows is either whitespace or the end of the input
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is not going to compile. which IDE are you using? You are not even initialize the variable `replaced` and `replaceAll()` method uses regular expression. change `replaceAll()` to `replace()`. Try something like this.

```
String replaced = "my-test (2)";
replaced = replaced.replace("my-test (2)", "test");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

First argument of replaceAll() method is regex. `"my-test (2)"` contains regex group "(2)".
so try to use something like `replaced.replaceAll("my-test \\(2\\)", "test"));`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using replaceAll() method, you can use **replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)**. This will remove all the occurrence of the given string with new one.
EX.

```
String sub=s.replace("my-test (2)", "test");
```